# How to get the number at the end of the url of an anchor using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor, href

My anchor tags inside a table row and are of the following form where the numbers at the end of the url can be any numer 1,9,100, 1049,... etc.

How can I get the number at the end of the url when an anchor is clicked? I can't even get the following to work.:

```
$('table').on('click', 'a', function (event) {
  alert($(this).attr('href').val());
});
```

```js
$('table').on('click', 'a', function (event) {
  alert($(this).attr('href').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="/ControllerName/ActionName/1">Order Detail</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="/ControllerName/ActionName/2">Order Detail</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  ...
  ...
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="/ControllerName/ActionName/100">Order Detail</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  ...
  ...
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="/ControllerName/ActionName/149">Order Detail</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  ...
  ...
</table>
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('href').match(/\d+$/)[0]`

Comment: @Tushar you should have written an actual answer. Please don't use the comments for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the digits at the end of the string, you can use RegEx `\d+$`. `\d+` will match one or more digits and `$`-ends with anchor will make the match at the end of line. So, this will match the number at the end of string.

```
$(this).attr('href').match(/\d+$/)[0]
```

`match()` will match the number and return an array. To get the number from zeroth index of array `[0]` is used. As suggested in other answers `this.href` can also be used to get the value of `href` attribute of the clicked element. Note that `this` inside event handler refer to the element on which event has occurred.

---

There are some issues in the code

```
$(table).on('click', a , function (event) {
   alert($(this).attr('href').val());
});
```

As I don't see `table` and `a` variables defined in the code given, I'm assuming that you're trying to use them as selectors.`$(table)` should be `$('table')` and `a` should be `$('a')`.

`$(this).attr('href')` will return the value of `href` attribute. So, there is no need to call `val()` on it. `val()` is used to get the element value(i.e. the value of `value` attribute on element).

The anchor click will redirect to the given URL. To stop this, you can use `event.preventDefault()` or add `return false` at the end of the event handler.

```js
$('table').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  console.log(this.href.match(/\d+$/)[0]);
  
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="/ControllerName/ActionName/1">Order Detail</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="/ControllerName/ActionName/2">Order Detail</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="/ControllerName/ActionName/100">Order Detail</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="/ControllerName/ActionName/149">Order Detail</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my errors and providing some details on some other aspects of jquery selectors.

Answer (score 1):

First you will want to put quotes around your tag specifiers in your query selectors. You might even change your query selector to be a single string (`table a` instead of `table`, `a`):

```
$('a').on('click', function (event) {
   alert($(this).attr('href').val());
});
```

Second, use the `split` function to convert the url string to an array based on the character `"/"`:

```
$('a').on('click', function (event) {
   var words = $(this).attr('href').split('/');
   alert(words[words.length-1]);
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/mspinks/088f8z8b/3/

Comment: My mistake. Taken care of.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.slice()`, `.lastIndexOf()`. Note, if `a` is not defined, missing quoutes surrounding selector `"a"` at delegated event.

```js
$("table").on("click", "a", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert(this.href.slice(this.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/ControllerName/ActionName/1">Order Detail</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/ControllerName/ActionName/2">Order Detail</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    ... ...
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/ControllerName/ActionName/100">Order Detail</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/ControllerName/ActionName/149">Order Detail</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regex, you can select a part of string. Write your regex in [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to run it and get result.

```
$("table").on('click', "a", function(event){
  alert(this.href.match(/\d+$/)[0]);
});
```

```js
$("table").on('click', "a", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.href.match(/\d+$/)[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="/ControllerName/ActionName/1">Order Detail</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="/ControllerName/ActionName/2">Order Detail</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  ...
  ...
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="/ControllerName/ActionName/100">Order Detail</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  ...
  ...
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="/ControllerName/ActionName/149">Order Detail</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  ...
  ...
</table>
```